# Socket connection issue on 3G in android

Tags: android, websocket, serversocket, faye

I have developed application. 
I have used socket connection.
I am able to open socket on wifi but unable to socket on 3G.
I have googled but not got any luck.

Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), port); 
this.socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(); 
this.socketChannel.configureBlocking(false); 
this.socketChannel.connect(socketAddress); // Create a Selector and attach to SocketChannel
Selector selector = Selector.open(); this.socketChannel.register(selector,
this.socketChannel.validOps());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code are you using for socket connection?

Comment: Look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305498/android-why-sending-information-to-server-works-with-wifi-only

Comment: @DJBurb I am using below code:
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), port);
this.socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
this.socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
this.socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);
// Create a Selector and attach to SocketChannel
Selector selector = Selector.open();
this.socketChannel.register(selector,
this.socketChannel.validOps());